# org.w3c.dom.DOMException: DOM005 Wrong document in Java while using Xcerces

Tags: java, dom, xerces

I am trying to use DocumentTypeImpl using Xcerces of JAVA .

Here is piece of code

```
Document htmlDoc = new MyHTMLDocumentImpl();

DocumentType docType = new DocumentTypeImpl(null, "html",
          "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN",
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd");
System.out.println("MAYYYYY docType"+docType);
System.out.println("JUNEEEE htmlDoc"+htmlDoc)
htmlDoc.appendChild(docType);
```

But I am getting following error while "appendChild" function
 I am facing following error

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: DOM005 Wrong document
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(ParentNode.java:393)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(ParentNode.java:325)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl.insertBefore(DocumentImpl.java:410)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:226)
        at main.document.MyHTMLDocumentImpl.makeBasicHtmlDoc(MyHTMLDocumentImpl.java:34)
        at main.parse.QtUiFileParser.parse(QtUiFileParser.java:52)
        at main.WebApplicationView.main(WebApplicationView.java:58)
```

Kindly Support

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `new DocumentTypeImpl(...)`.

Use `htmlDoc.getImplementation().createDocumentType(...)`

Comment: Sorry I am new to Java.I have added like this.       DocumentType docType = document.getImplementation().createDocumentType(null, "html",  But getting error as. canot find symbol "document"

Comment: Sorry, it's `htmlDoc`, not `document`. I'll correct the answer

Comment: this is my changed code       Document htmlDoc = new MyHTMLDocumentImpl();
      DocumentType docType = htmlDoc.getImplementation().createDocumentType( "html",
              "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN",
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd");
       System.out.println("aprrr docType"+docType);
      htmlDoc.appendChild(docType); Getting same error as above.

Comment: You should look into DocumentBuilderFactory and DocumentBuilder rather than MyHTMLDocumentImpl too.

Comment: I have checked in Buider Factory i.e. in my java code.Problem is in    Document htmlDoc = MyHTMLDocumentImpl.makeBasicHtmlDoc("My Title");
 this statement.

Comment: When I print docType it gives me NULL.Is it ok.?